# Python stop a thread after n seconds

Tags: python, python-3.6

How can i stop a thread after 5 seconds? I want to print "Hello World" every seconds and then stop after 5 seconds. This is my code:

```
import threading

def printthis():
   threading.Timer(1.0, printthis).start()
   print("Hello, World!")

printthis()
```

Comment: Have a counter passed as an argument that will stop the recursion after call #5

Comment: Can you do a demo for me?

Comment: How about you try to write a demo, for practice?

Comment: The code that i posted is just a sample. Anyways, i already got it.

Comment: @Jaypee since your question is definitely going to be useful to others , I suggest posting an answer. If the answer is good, you can get lots of rep from it.

Comment: On the other hand, if we can be of no further use to you, please consider deleting the question entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
def printthis():
    print_count = 0
    while print_count < 5: # 5 because print_count will be 5 after printing the 5th time
        threading.Timer(1.0, printthis).start()
        print("Hello, World!")
        print_count += 1 
printthis()
```